# HC-05/Arduino receiving spam data

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-05

I connected everything properly. On the first try I did receive data as  I was supposed to. I then wrote some logic, re-uploaded and started receiving crazy spam.

My serial monitor is getting spammed with:

- question marks if the variable is `char`, or;
- `25252525252` if the variable is `int`, or;
- `-1` if variable is `String`.

I'm monitoring at 38400 baud which is the same as my `Serial.begin()`.

Any ideas ?

Code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>

Adafruit_PWMServoDriver pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();

#define MIN_PULSE_WIDTH 650
#define MAX_PULSE_WIDTH 2350
#define DEFAULT_PULSE_WIDTH 1500
#define FREQUENCY 50

char data = 'a';

void setup()
{
  analogReference(DEFAULT);

  Serial.begin(38400);

  pwm.begin();
  pwm.setPWMFreq(FREQUENCY);
  Serial.println("hello world");
}

void loop()
{
  data = Serial.read();
  Serial.println(data);
  Serial.flush();
  if (data == 'a'){
    pwm.setPWM(0, 0, pulseWidth(90));
  }
  if (data == 's'){
    pwm.setPWM(0, 0, pulseWidth(30));
  }
  delay(1000);
  //printing time in seconds  
}

int pulseWidth(int angle)
{
  int pulse_wide, analog_value;
  pulse_wide = map(angle, 0, 180, MIN_PULSE_WIDTH, MAX_PULSE_WIDTH);
  analog_value = int(float(pulse_wide) / 1000000 * FREQUENCY * 4096);

  return analog_value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work for the spam. I changed my variable to integer and tried sending a number. No matter what I send, I receive either 120, 128 or 248, multiple times. What's the deal ?

Comment: you should first connect the Arduino to Serial Monitor and learn the basics of Serial communication on examples

Comment: It does, but why is it the same no matter what character I send ?

Comment: I cannot use answer since I am not logged in, which I cannot do since I have my password on remember on another machine.
I changed print to write, however I still am getting weird results.
1 corresponds to "x?" (with a reverse question mark) and 2 corresponds to "???". I'm so lost.

Comment: has the BT module a baud rate 38400 baud?

Answer (score 2):

`Serial.read()` returns -1 if no data is available. It doesn't wait for the byte. Test for -1 or use `Serial.available()` as any example does.

Replace `Serial.print(data)` with `Serial.write(data)` to get the data echoed back unchanged.